# How to concatenate values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

> A B C D E ... 
>   1| 1 0 0 1 0
>   2| 0 1 0 0 1
>   3| 0 0 0 1 0
>   4| 1 0 0 0 0

I'd like to concatenate row 1 in column F so that it returns: 10010

But entering `=concatenate(A1:E1)` returns an error `#VALUE!` and using an array formula (`{=concatenate(A1:E1)}`) returns just 1.

[This method](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/) gets me close, but it removes the formula so I can't drag down and concatenate all rows.

Why does Excel make concatenating so hard? Is there another way to do this without using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **F1** enter:

```
=A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 & E1
```

and copy down.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If you want to bite the bullet and use *VBA,* then consider this tiny *UDF*

```
Public Function KonKatenate(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rIN
        KonKatenate = KonKatenate & r.Text
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=KonKatenate(A1:Z1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

The `CONCATENATE` function in Excel is frustratingly limited. As far as I can see, your only option for having a fill-able concatenation formula is to bite the bullet and enter the address of each term as a separate argument.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1)
```

Sorry, that's the best I can offer without VBA. I hope you don't have a ton of columns.

Comment: I do have lots of columns. Of course I do! I'll mark this correct unless there's a deus ex machina of an answer in the next couple days.