# Match each row against all other rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 53 rows with 25 columns of text values. Is there a formula that will match each row against all other rows? I basically need a similarity matrix and am wondering if there is a shorter way than comparing each row with the rest doing just two at a time?

Comment: Can you mock up a smaller table (say 5 rows by 3 rows) and show us what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires a two fold approach to solve this.

**Step-1**: Concatenate all the values.
Use this response from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/882614/how-to-concatenate-values-in-excel?answertab=active#tab-top) to achieve concatenation of a range of cells (which normally wouldn't be possible).  See image below.
[image]
In the above image the text highlighted in yellow are the data (5X5 in my case and 53X25 in your case). In the last column, I have `konkatenate` the data

**Step-2**: Now that you have the concatenated values you can compare individual cells (which effectively is the combination of a complete row).
In my example above, I have used conditional formatting to identify the duplicate rows, which may or may not match what you need.